# JS for binding printers on client machine

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

Is there any any javascript to

```
bind all printers on the client machine
```

into a drop down list

Comment: To my knowledge, you can't do it with javascript alone.

Comment: did you see my answer, what is your backend ?? you need backend support for sure.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer to this is "No". You *can* do it from VBScript depending on the user's security settings but that's not helpful for most browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with JavaScript, inside the browser? NO. (period)
for explanation, refer http://www.codestyle.org/javascript/faq-Browser.shtml#printerselection